# How to deserialize a empty JSON array

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a JSON file that looks like the following:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 20,
  "skills": [
  ]
}
```

The `skills` item, if it's not empty, looks like the following:

```
{
   "skills": [
       "skill_1": {
   },
   "skill_2": {
   }]
}
```

And I need to deserialize this JSON content to [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object):

```
public class Profile {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = SkillsMapDeserializer.class)
    public Map<String, Skill> skills;
}
public class Skill {
    public String skillName;
    public int age;
}
```

And my `SkillsMapDeserializer` looks like the following:

```
public class SkillsMapDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map<String, Skill>> {
    @Override
    public Map<String, Skill> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final Map<String, Skill> map = jsonParser.readValueAs(new TypeReference<Map<String, Skill>>() {
        });
        if (map == null) {
            return new HashMap<>();
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

If the `skills` item isn't empty all works fine, but if the `skills` is an empty array, I get an exception that looks like the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of START_ARRAY token
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: a workaround: use 2 steps: read value as a list of Skills first, check if it's empty and if not, add the values to a map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your JSON data, it seem *skills* is an array of objects.

```
"skills": [],
 "skills": [
   "skill_1": {},
   "skill_2": {}
 ]
```

But your Java code defines it as *Map*:

```
public Map<String, Skill> skills;
```

That's why you got an exception when trying to convert the array to a map directly.
If you can't change the [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object)'s Profile, you should have an intermediate step to convert the list to a Map.

```
public class SkillsMapDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map<String, Skill>> {
    @Override
    public Map<String, Skill> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final List<Map<String,Skill>> skills = jsonParser.readValueAs(new TypeReference<List<Map<String,Skill>>>>() {
        });
        return functionConvertListToMapWithParam(skills);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

skills is not a map. it should be list of objects. try to modify your POJO like below:-

```
public class Profile {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("age")
    private Integer age;
    @JsonProperty("skills")
    private List < Object > skills = null;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("age")
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @JsonProperty("age")
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @JsonProperty("skills")
    public List < Object > getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    @JsonProperty("skills")
    public void setSkills(List < Object > skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }

}
```

Comment: ```skills``` it is a map. and this approach doesn't suitable for me.